# ./gradlew bundleRelease Error: Cannot find symbol ReactNativeFlipper

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build, bundle

When bundling my react native app for android using ./gradlew bundleRelease I get the following error:

```
android/app/src/main/java/com/project/MainApplication.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
      ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper
```

When running it normally with `npx expo run:android` it works fine. Ive made sure my packages are the same, names are the same, and my imports are correct.

MainApplication.java

```
package com.project;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.config.ReactFeatureFlags;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import expo.modules.ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher;
import expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapper;

import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
    new ReactNativeHostWrapper(this, new DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
      @Override
      public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
      }

      @Override
      protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
        List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
        // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
        // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
        return packages;
      }

      @Override
      protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
        return ".expo/.virtual-metro-entry";
      }

      @Override
      protected boolean isNewArchEnabled() {
        return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
      }

      @Override
      protected Boolean isHermesEnabled() {
        return BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED;
      }
  });

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    if (!BuildConfig.REACT_NATIVE_UNSTABLE_USE_RUNTIME_SCHEDULER_ALWAYS) {
      ReactFeatureFlags.unstable_useRuntimeSchedulerAlways = false;
    }
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
      DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load();
    }
    if (BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE == "debug") {
      ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
    }
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onApplicationCreate(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onConfigurationChanged(this, newConfig);
  }
}
```

I added the if statement that checks if the project is running in 'debug' variant - but this doesn't work if you build in 'release' because BuildConfig is not created.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36091https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36091)?

Comment: Link doesn't work ://

Comment: Sorry. [https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36091](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36091) is the link

Comment: Yes, I have visited this, and pretty much every other link on Google. Ive noticed that building in 'debug' variant creates a BuildConfig file, but when creating in 'release' it doesn't, which seems to create the error. So maybe the config file is not being created?

Comment: Yeah I think the same. Would be great if you can share your MainApplication.java

Comment: Just updated the main post. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I edited the gradle properties to include the BuildConfig. Now for some reason that If (BuildConfig.DEBUG) ALWAYS runs the code inside, even though BuildConifg.DEBUG is false... any ideas?